# Calcular maximo y minimo sin iniciar las variables C#

Tags: c#, bucle-for, condiciones

Quisiera saber como sacar el valor máximo y mínimo sin inicializar las variables y sin tener que pedir un número fuera del ciclo for, es decir usando banderas. Me pide hacer lo siguiente: Ingresar 5 números por consola, guardandolos en una variable escalar. Luego calcular y mostrar el valor máximo, el valor mínimo, y el promedio.

```
        int numero;
        int i;
        int minimo = 0; //no deberia estar inicializado en cero
        int maximo = 0; //no deberia estar inicializado en cero
        int acumulador = 0;
        int contador = 0;
        float promedio;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese un numero: ");
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            acumulador += numero;
            contador++;              

            if (numero > maximo)
            {
                maximo = numero;
            }
            if(numero < minimo)
            {
                minimo = numero;
            }                                             
        }

        promedio = (float)(acumulador / contador);

        Console.WriteLine("Minimo: {0}, Maximo: {1}, Promedio: {2}", minimo, maximo, promedio);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quisiera saber como sacar el valor máximo y mínimo sin inicializar las variables y sin tener que pedir un número fuera del ciclo for, **es decir usando banderas**.

Esto no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

> Ingresar 5 números por consola, guardandolos en una variable escalar. Luego calcular y mostrar el valor máximo, el valor mínimo, y el promedio.

Esta segunda parte se contradice con la primera que escribiste.

---

No puedes pedir calcular el máximo y el mínimo de una colección de datos sin inicializar variables, primero porque no sabrás que valor tienen inicialmente, según la [especificación del lenguaje C#, apartado "variables"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables) (traducción mía):

> #### Variables locales
>
> ...
>   Una variable local introducida por una *declaración_de_variable_local* no se inicializa automáticamente y en consecuencia no tiene un valor por defecto. [...] una variable local introducida por una *declaración_de_variable_local* se considera inicialmente no-asignada.

Si el compilador detecta que puede dejar una variable entera local sin inicializar de manera segura, la podría dejar con un valor indeterminado; en caso contrario podría dejarla a cero.

Así que supongamos que estás usando variables sin inicializar (como dices en la primera parte de tu pregunta) y supongamos que se inicializan a cero; en ese caso tu código será completamente incapaz de detectar el valor mínimo (a no ser que el valor mínimo sea menor o igual a cero) ya que cualquier valor será mayor que el cero que contiene tu variable sin inicializar.

Supongamos ahora que las variables se inicializan a un valor indeterminado; en ese caso tu código será completamente incapaz de detectar el valor máximo (a no ser que el valor máximo sea mayor o igual a ese valor indeterminado).

Por lo tanto, toda tu pregunta parte de una premisa falsa: **SI** debes inicializar las variables, la variable del valor máximo al mínimo almacenable por un entero y la variable del valor mínimo al máximo:

```
int minimo = Int32.MaxValue;
int maximo = Int32.MinValue;
float acumulador = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    Console.Write("Ingrese un numero: ");
    var numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    acumulador += numero;
    maximo = numero > maximo ? numero : maximo;
    minimo = numero < minimo ? numero : minimo;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Minimo: {minimo}, Maximo: {maximo}, Promedio: {acumulador / 5}");
```

Y segundo, porque [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) no permite el uso de variables sin inicializar, si dejamos `maximo` y `minimo` sin inicialización obtenemos el error:

> ```
> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'maximo'
> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'minimo'
> ```

Puedes ver el código fallando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHPS8MwFMfPzV/xGB5apput7rJuevA0sDAU9CAeHm0sD5oEknRMRv/2mqStbkIgj@/7vN@luSmV5n3fGpI1vH4by0XOygaNgb1WtUYBJxYZi5ZKOCiqoECSsbHaBXx8AuraJB6JSFoQJEmofLmELeykvcsWBR7fsGl5PhF4/E@Q/CW@GoUWsGxF22CltINuc@Ydzo59PAXJfRtY5TCfU@K8vnz0pKRRDV@8a7I8nu1krbnh0EqQreBarWGW@BrRAfUouVwu52KP2vB4in/hWD2T5HGShNLRWTvz7RgZEg2zwKTBwzgdPE7Kepo34GE5f/hmXNcFPizQ4Z2vfTFTaOpqVgRkDaeB7a7dRY6jEgynuNMJXpHXzrpfwqoLO@hY1/cpS1N2n7HMPfYD)</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

También puedes utilizar una lista de enteros y realizar los cálculos que necesites con LINQ:

```
var numeros = new List<int> { 8, 2, 6, 3, 1 };
```

O bien pidiendo por consola:

```
var numeros = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
Console.Write("Ingrese un numero: ");
numeros.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

y los cálculos:

```
int minimo = numeros.Min(); 
int maximo = numeros.Max(); 
double promedio = numeros.Average();
```